# External SSD with Linux Mint installed not booting

Tags: linux-mint, boot, external-hdd

I managed to install Linux Mint on my external SSD from a bootable USB on a friend's laptop. On my friends laptop (which is a Lenovo) it worked well, but on my Latop for some reason it doesn't boot up.

[Here](https://snipboard.io/sdA30M.jpg) is my BIOS configuration.

When I press <kbd>F9</kbd> the SSD doesn't even appear as a choice for booting. Any ideas?

Things I tried:

- installing debian by burning it on the same SSD I would install it into and I got this error [here](https://snipboard.io/SD07iL.jpg)
- changing BIOS order of boot (which is ok now and doesn't work)
- installed OS to external USB drive and booting up from it and it didnt work as well, so the fault is not on the SSD as expected

Laptop is an HP g8 250

Comment: Is your USB in the firmare set to initialize all devices?

Comment: how do i check that??
is there any of these choices shown on the link i posted for the firmware settings?

Comment: If you have another USB drive, for example a simple USB pendrive, you can create a live drive by cloning from a Linux Mint 21 iso file to the USB drive. Please notice that this will overwrite everything, so don't use a drive, where you have [unique] data that you cannot afford to lose. Try to boot into this drive. If it does not work, the problem is in the computer, most likely in the BIOS system (or otherwise a hardware problem). If it works to boot the live USB drive, the problem is with your installed system in the external SSD.

Comment: External drive needs its own ESP - efi system partition with boot files. For external devices, the default boot file is /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. With Ubuntu you also must have /EFI/ubunu folder for grub, not sure with Mint. You may just need to create an ESP anywhere on drive if not over 2TB and reinstall grub in UEFI boot mode. Use gparted to create FAT32 with esp,boot flags & Boot-Repair to reinstall grub. I believe Mint uses Ubuntu's installer. See this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: To change the boot order:
1. Insert the USB drive;
2. Access the system Startup menu;
For computers or tablets with keyboards attached, turn on or restart the computer or tablet, 
quickly **press esc , then press f9** for boot options.
For tablets without keyboards, turn on or restart the tablet, quickly press and hold the volume up 
button, and then select f9. ‒  or – Turn on or restart the tablet, quickly press and hold the volume down button, and then select f9;
3. Select the optical drive or USB flash  drive from which you want to boot, and then follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: @sudodus the ssd that i have installed ubuntu (now) is not showing in the menu when i press F9 
And i face errors when i try to install a Linux os on my external usb andc and cant really just clone the os to it dunno why with aomei

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Live or installed? Live is typically created by cloning from an iso file, installed is typically created by installing from a live system, but can also be created by [extracting and] cloning from a [compressed] image file like what I suggested in a comment to your question at AskUbuntu. Can you boot into some other USB drive (for example a USB pendrive with a live system)? Or is there no boot option available for USB? In that case, is it possible to select some other hotkey (maybe the escape key) and enter into the BIOS menus and there modify what can be booted?

Comment: I installed ubuntu to an external ssd from burning the iso file to a usb stick.
Now im trying to clone the installed image of ubuntu from the ssd to usb (because i couldnt install Ubuntu to usb, installer crashed a lot of times) and i cant find a way (AOMEI doesnt work).
There is no boot option available for usb but when i have ubuntu burnt onto it i can try the OS. 
If you mean changing the boot order i have done it from the BIOS as shown on the question. If you like see the question i added things i tried

Comment: @Yanis, 1. What do you mean by "changing bios order of boot (which is ok now and doesnt work)"? Can you boot this computer from a live USB pendrive? 2. I think you have better chances to succeed, if you try according to [**this link**](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692) (that I suggested  in a comment to your question at AskUbuntu). Scroll down [in the linked thread at the Ubuntu Forums] to find how you can install a graphical desktop environment, for example `lubuntu desktop` or `ubuntu desktop' or any of the Ubuntu community flavours.

Comment: Managed to install ubuntu in an external usb stick but it doesn get recognised either.  So i tried downloading the link with the compressed image but it doesnt download from the forum and i downloaded it from here, its the same right? https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily-preinstalled/20221019/ .... I just need to download and extract it on my external ssd right??? @sudodus

Comment: Yes, I think it is OK. An alternative is [http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/) which contains the long term support version 22.04 LTS version (more stable, longer lifetime), but if your computer is too new for 22.04 LTS, the kinetic version is a better choice (kinetic alias version 22.10 released a few days ago). And yes, extract it into your external drive and it should work without tweaking (at least wired internet (ethernet) should work, and later install driver for wifi).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140151/discussion-between-sudodus-and-yanis).

Comment: There MIGHT be a setting in Configuration "USB Legacy support" or similar. It's usually on the Configuration or Main tab.

Comment: @stoney there is no sucj configuration on my BIOS

Comment: Ok, from some research: HP is famous for USB Boot-Problems. It seems to need UEFI Boot with certain firmwares (not necessarily UEFI Secure boot though). Try the USB-C jack (helped some). If it doesn't show the

Comment: currently i dont have a usb to usb-c converter. 
DO you know if i could install any kind of specific firmware that could help solve the issue?